# PHP delete one value in .txt

Tags: php

i have data that saved in save.txt
below is the content...

A;;;

B;;;

C;;;B

D;;;A

E;;;B

F;;;C

How to delete the A and B values in PHP?

```
$pick= file_get_contents('save.txt');
$rows= explode("\n", $pick);
array_shift($rows);
foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
    $row_data = explode(";",$data);
    echo $row_data[0].'-'.$row_data[3].'<br/>';
    if($row_data[3]==false)
    {
        //here is the command
    }
}
```

please help me. thankyou :)

Comment: `$pick` is already a `string`, why not use `str_replace()`? What do you intend to do with the result?

Answer (score 0):

At face value...

```
$pick= file_get_contents('save.txt');
$pick=str_replace(array('A','B'),'',$pick);
```

But why do I have a sneaking suspicion there's more to this story...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code :

```
$pick = file_get_contents('save.txt');
$pick = preg_replace('/(A|B)/', '', $pick);
file_put_contents('save.txt', $pick);
```